# app crash by the error shown in logcat in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

i am facing the app crash error in android studio when app try to run and the error which logcat is showing is below:
**

- com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/System: Uncaught exception
  thrown by finalizer 06-29 18:19:05.002
  2840-2849/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/System:
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
  'boolean java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue.isEmpty()' on a null
  object reference

**
the home activity and welcome activity is written below

this is the **welcome activity**

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    Thread th = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent home = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(home);
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

}

and now this is **home activity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
```

}
in here home activity is not ready yet because i am working on the welcome activity. please help me to solve my issue thank you

Comment: Use Handler for delaying.

Comment: Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent home = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(home);
            }
        },5000);

Comment: @Opriday where should i use this handler after try{} or where kindly guide me

Comment: thank you error is gone now thank you for your help :)